# Add seed to the node editor

Tags: node-editor

I wanted to add a seed to the node editor for a volume texture, but i not know where I can find. My idea is to get a new texture every time. Can you help me [image]

Comment: "Every time" you do what?

Comment: A new texture with the same nodes

Answer (score 2):

Add a mapping node between the Texture coordinates and the Musgrave texture one and then animate the value of one of the 3 axis in the Location Value:
[image]

Comment: No problem, just set the answer as the right one with the green tick under it :)